# How do I make every triangle to quad at once?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, faces

Is there a way to make every triangle back to quads? It looks like i have press something wrong yesterday and now every quad is a triangle. Is there a quick solution? Or do I have to press f thousands of times now?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, finally press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to convert tris to quads.

sample video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKDWW10IJoo&feature=emb_logo